# how to convert pointer to integer in c?

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion, integer

the easiest way to fix this, please show your work

**attempt**

```
int x = (int)p
```

**error**

warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]

Comment: Why do you want to convert your pointer to an integer?

Comment: My professor wants me to implement my own version of sizeof.

Comment: Replace `int` by `intptr_t` after having read [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to use an integer type to hold a pointer value is to use `uintptr_t` type.

From the `C11`, chapter 7.20.1.4,

> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> ```
>  uintptr_t
> ```

If you want a signed integer type instead, use `intptr_t`.

Comment: I'm getting an unknown type. Wut library this is?

Comment: Did you include `<stdint.h>`?

Comment: I don't really need to convert the thing back. Is there was a way to suppress the warning?

Comment: `Is there was a way to suppress the warning?`, yes, by writing proper code.

Comment: I probably should have been more specific in my question but I'm not allowed to use other libraries. But this does work for me now ty.

Comment: Just quoting from draft is not very helpful in this case. I would suggest to add an example to the answer which explains the use of `uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`.

Comment: @solidwaterslayer What other libraries are you talking about? This is a type defined in the said header file- that's all.

Comment: @haccks It's not that hard to replace the type lol.

Comment: I found that I can use the -w flag for gcc to suppress all the warnings so this question is done.